# Runtime Error: out of gas

Tags: web3js, testrpc, out-of-gas

I'm new user of Ethereum.
My error :

```
Runtime Error: out of gas
```

My contract :
https://github.com/cbourree/test/wiki

I compile with : https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.0+commit.acd334c9.js

"web3 deployed" generate with solidity : https://github.com/cbourree/test/wiki/Compiled-contract

I run `testrpc -u 0 -u 1`

On Chrome Console :

```
I run "web3 deployed" commandes
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance("0xafd05e5884d2cccc947b76da3e4af9025b677002"), "ether").toNumber(); //0xaf...002 address of my contract
```

WORK (return 10 Eth) !
But :

```
roulette.betEven(10, { from: web3.eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether") })
```

->Error : out of gas

The code comes from this tutorial : https://www.ethereum-france.com/ecrire-une-dapp-pour-ethereum-1-smart-contract/

**Edit** : I can execute the contract in truffle console without error

**EDIT 2**

When i run

```
roulette.betOdd({ from: web3.eth.accounts[1] })
```

then

```
roulette.betOdd({ from: web3.eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(10, "ether") })
```

I havn't error. But i don't understand why ???

Comment: Are you running the contract with the owner account?

Comment: No, but i try also  without succes :'( What is the time required for the contract to be accessible ? Because i don't know why but my old contract can run now

Answer (score 2):

your code is unclear for me but I think the problem is generated by the modifier

```
modifier bankMustBeAbleToPayForBetType(BetType betType) {
    uint necessaryBalance = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < bets.length; i++) {
        necessaryBalance += getPayoutForType(bets[i].betType) * bets[i].value;
    }
    necessaryBalance += getPayoutForType(betType) * msg.value;
    if (necessaryBalance > this.balance) throw;
    _;
}
```

maybe  the (necessaryBalance > this.balance)  check their values

Comment: Thanks for response but i try to unuse the modifier -> function betEven(uint number) public payable transactionMustContainEther() {

Comment: Why do you think it comes from the modifier?
I tried to bypass the modifier, so not to use it in the code, but it still isn't working.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: i ve only debugged it